# VBA Macro to copy different cell values in a Notepad

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the different cells data into a notepad. How do i do that.
Example : values from row3 column B(B3), then from row3 column E(E3).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want values from 3rd row column B , then from 4th row column C.

Comment: Imran: talking to yourself? You can edit your question (click the edit link). Note that the actual columns you want don't change the answer. Of course you can choose them yourself. In my answer, pick `Range("$B$3,$C$4")` (or use the `Selection` as I suggested)

Answer (score 2):

Using a helper module you could:

```
 Dim cell As Range
 Dim concat As String
 For Each cell In Range("$B$3,$E$3")
    concat = concat & vbCrLf & cell.Value
 Next

 ' Debug.Print concat
 Text2Clipboard concat
```

If instead of `Range("$B$3,$E$3")` you said `Selection` you'd end up with all the cells currently selected.

**Hint**: You can select inidivual cells using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd>

You need the following helper definitions somewhere in your VBA project (I suggest a module named like 'Clipboard'):

```
Declare Function abOpenClipboard Lib "User32" Alias "OpenClipboard" (ByVal Hwnd As Long) As Long
Declare Function abCloseClipboard Lib "User32" Alias "CloseClipboard" () As Long
Declare Function abEmptyClipboard Lib "User32" Alias "EmptyClipboard" () As Long
Declare Function abIsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "User32" Alias "IsClipboardFormatAvailable" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Declare Function abSetClipboardData Lib "User32" Alias "SetClipboardData" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Declare Function abGetClipboardData Lib "User32" Alias "GetClipboardData" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Declare Function abGlobalAlloc Lib "Kernel32" Alias "GlobalAlloc" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Declare Function abGlobalLock Lib "Kernel32" Alias "GlobalLock" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Declare Function abGlobalUnlock Lib "Kernel32" Alias "GlobalUnlock" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Boolean
Declare Function abLstrcpy Lib "Kernel32" Alias "lstrcpyA" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long
Declare Function abGlobalFree Lib "Kernel32" Alias "GlobalFree" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Declare Function abGlobalSize Lib "Kernel32" Alias "GlobalSize" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Const GHND = &H42
Const CF_TEXT = 1
Const APINULL = 0

Function Text2Clipboard(szText As String)
    Dim wLen As Integer
    Dim hMemory As Long
    Dim lpMemory As Long
    Dim retval As Variant
    Dim wFreeMemory As Boolean

    ' Get the length, including one extra for a CHR$(0) at the end.
    wLen = Len(szText) + 1
    szText = szText & Chr$(0)
    hMemory = abGlobalAlloc(GHND, wLen + 1)
    If hMemory = APINULL Then
        MsgBox "Unable to allocate memory."
        Exit Function
    End If
    wFreeMemory = True
    lpMemory = abGlobalLock(hMemory)
    If lpMemory = APINULL Then
        MsgBox "Unable to lock memory."
        GoTo T2CB_Free
    End If

    ' Copy our string into the locked memory.
    retval = abLstrcpy(lpMemory, szText)
    ' Don't send clipboard locked memory.
    retval = abGlobalUnlock(hMemory)

    If abOpenClipboard(0&) = APINULL Then
        MsgBox "Unable to open Clipboard.  Perhaps some other application is using it."
        GoTo T2CB_Free
    End If
    If abEmptyClipboard() = APINULL Then
        MsgBox "Unable to empty the clipboard."
        GoTo T2CB_Close
    End If
    If abSetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMemory) = APINULL Then
        MsgBox "Unable to set the clipboard data."
        GoTo T2CB_Close
    End If
    wFreeMemory = False

T2CB_Close:
    If abCloseClipboard() = APINULL Then
        MsgBox "Unable to close the Clipboard."
    End If
    If wFreeMemory Then GoTo T2CB_Free
    Exit Function

T2CB_Free:
    If abGlobalFree(hMemory) <> APINULL Then
        MsgBox "Unable to free global memory."
    End If
End Function
```

Notes

- code 'borrowed' from http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Copying-data-to-and-from-the-Clipboard-(Acc-95%2B)
- tested in Excel 2003 on Windows XP SP3

Comment: ... and finally, open Notepad and paste. I guess this is a correct solution, if you want to take the question literally down to the letter! "copy the different cells data into a notepad" *can* be done by emulating a human doing a copy-paste, but why not just write to a text file?? Anyway, +1 for the informative value.

Comment: @Jean-François: fair enough, I guess; In interpreted 'copy to notepad' to indicate 'as plain text', and writing to a file would be *a lot* less flexible (figure this: how big are the odds he really wanted the data in notepad only?). Also, I don't want to take questions literally (I suggest using the Selection instead of some random fixed range). However, experience shows that answers are getting best understanding if they refer tightly to the original question (wording, samples), even if the details are immaterial. Connecting to the question is the extra mile, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Write your cell values to a text file, then open it in Notepad or your favourite text editor.

```
' Write to file.
Open "C:\temp.txt" For Output As #1
Print #1, Range("B3").Value, Range("C4").Value
Print #1, Range("Q981").Value, "hello world!" ' or whatever else
Close #1
' Now open it in notepad.
Shell ("notepad ""C:\temp.txt""")
```